# Writing the contents of a ByteBuffer to a DataOutput?

Tags: java, bytebuffer, dataoutputstream

The object to which I need to write a ByteBuffer is typed as an instance of interface *DataOutput*, rather than as an instance of class *DataOutputStream* (which implements DataOutput). I need to assume ByteBuffer.hasArray() can return false, so I don't have access to any underlying array.

Neither DataOutput nor DataOutputStream provide a write method that accepts a ByteBuffer. However, writing a ByteBuffer to a DataOutputStream can be done with a WritableByteChannel, obtained by passing the OutputStream to a utility method of the Channels class. But DataOutput is not type compatible with OutputStream, and no analogous utility method exists.

Does the SDK provide any efficient routines for doing this? I would rather not have to create an intermediate byte array and loop through the ByteBuffer with bulk get operations (effectively replicating the code of WritableByteChannel implementations).

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a one-liner for this. A simple while loop should be enough:

```
DataOutput out = ...
ByteBuffer bb = ...
while (bb.hasRemaining()) {
  out.writeByte(bb.get());
}
```

Comment: While that would work and is a reasonable solution for relatively small buffers, it's probably inefficient for the largish buffers I can be expecting. I didn't mention that in my question, though.

Comment: With this approach there is no intermediate array creation. The only question is what is the implementation of the `DataOutput` and how is it flushed. Perhaps I'm missing something, but what problem could there be for a large `ByteBuffer`?

Comment: Your while loop involves two method invocations per byte, whereas an intermediate array involved in a bulk get/write can be used by the implementations of ByteBuffer and DataOutput to perform what are likely to be more efficient array copies of many bytes at a time. Even though I can't access the underlying array of the ByteBuffer, it will probably be backed by one regardless. Same goes for the DataOuput object.